# Ubuntu 12.10 overheats and fan runs high

Tags: fan, jupiter, heat

I have the problem with my fan constantly and hot CPU. I have a Dell Inspirion 15r special edition. I followed the instructions to load Jupiter to solve this but when I enter:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webup8team/jupiter`

I get the following error:

```
Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/API/1.0/~webup8team/+archive/Jupiter) to get PPA information, please check your Internet connection
```

and Internet is working

My specs are:

```
Inspiron 15 R Special Edition,BTX,7520
Intel Core 3rd Generation Processor,I7-3612QM,  4Core
32G Solid State Drive,ISRT,A5
PWA,Daughterboard, SATA,7520
HARD DRIVE,1 Terabyte,5.4 krpm
8 GB Dual Channel DDR3 SDRAM
Intel (R) HD Graphics 4000
AMD Radeon HD 7730M
15.6 Full HD  1080 pixel LED Display
```

Ubuntu 12.10 is loaded as a dual boot alone on the 32 GB Solid State Drive.

Answer (score 2):

For the error that you mention it is because the URL is wrong, if you try to get there you will get:

[image]

You actually want this URL: `https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/jupiter`

So I suggest 2 things:

1. First try to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and see if the URL that throws you the error is found there. If it is, change it to the correct one and update your repositories afterwards.
2. Edit your **Software Sources**. Simply open the Dash and type Software Sources. That should open the Software Sources window. On the second tab, the one that says **Other Software** find the PPA for Jupiter and remove that (Both, the source repository and the actual compiled repository for Jupiter).

   [image]

Then open a terminal, update your repositories again like:

`sudo apt-get update`.

Then proceed to add the Jupiter PPA shown in https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/jupiter
It should look like this when on the terminal:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter`

Then do `sudo apt-get update` to update the repositories again.

For the heat problem I would suggest:

- Clean the laptop a bit (Just in case there is dust or something clogging the air flow)
- Use the laptop in a position that makes sure it has enough space underneath it.
- Anything that actually contributes to better air flow.

After you have solved the Jupiter problem (If you can not find it, just re-add the PPA using `add-apt-repository` it will take care of checking for anything missing. Maybe it had a problem when adding it the first time.

For the cooling part I also recommend using `powertop`. Install it by:

`sudo apt-get install powertop`

Then run the app like `sudo powertop` and go to the last TAB that has a column (The first column actually) that says **BAD** or **GOOD**. Go to all the ones that say BAD and start pressing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to improve/fix them so they help in generating less heat and less power usage.

Last I want to point you to this question: [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed?rq=1)

It has solved many users problems related to Fan speed: [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed?rq=1)

Although again I would recommend checking into why the temperature is so high since the fan speed is higher, the higher the temperature of the CPU/GPU. So first check in Windows or physically the laptop for clean air circulation. Then proceed with the question.

**HYBRID PROBLEMS**

Since you have a Hybrid Laptop (It means it has 2 video cards, an Intel one and an Ati one) I did some research and found some links that might help or give you an idea of where to go:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=5275392
(Research about DELL Laptops and Fan problems)

[Is Dell Inspiron 15R Special Edition compatible with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187144/is-dell-inspiron-15r-special-edition-compatible-with-ubuntu) (Information about this particular model)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=842775
(A solution that might work with the Fan issues)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2095880
(Question about the same issue)

[How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/ubuntu-12-10-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-not-working)
(Fix for graphic problems. See NOTE1 for some additional information at the bottom.)

[Dell Inspiron 15R [Special Edition] fan speed problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230232/dell-inspiron-15r-special-edition-fan-speed-problem)
(Link about checking BIOS for an option to remove one of the 2 video cards)

From all of this, the only one that actually went to where I was thinking was one that mentioned installing some Fan controlling  packages (The i8k). I believe this could be a solution since it involves checking the sensors (Which also made me suggest to install lm-sensors). So here is a small guide to try it out:

1. `sudo apt-get install i8kutils`
2. `sudo gedit /etc/modules`
3. Add in a new line **i8k** and save the file. It should look similar to this (Look at last line):

   [image]
4. `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/options`
5. Add in a new line **options i8k force=1** and save the file. It should look like this:

   [image]
6. Reboot the computer. Type `sudo reboot` if you want.
7. `sudo gedit /etc/i8kmon`
8. Paste in the file the following information and save it:

(Copy the data and paste that in the file)

```
# Run as daemon, override with --daemon option
set config(daemon)      0

# Automatic fan control, override with --auto option
set config(auto)        1

# Report status on stdout, override with --verbose option
set config(verbose) 1

# Status check timeout (seconds), override with --timeout option
set config(timeout) 1

# Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
set config(0)   {{-1 0}  -1  55  -1  55}
set config(1)   {{-1 1}  55  70  55  70}
set config(3)   {{-1 2}  70  128  70  128}

# For computer with 2 fans, use a variant of this instead:
# Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
# set config(0) {{-1 0}  -1  52  -1  65}
# set config(1) {{-1 1}  41  66  55  75}
# set config(2) {{-1 1}  55  80  65  85}
# set config(3) {{-1 2}  70 128  75 128}

# end of file
```

Now reboot. Although before doing that, install lmsensors and make it detect every sensor you have:

`sudo apt-get install lm-sensors`

`sudo sensors-detect`

Wait for it to finish. Every time it asks for something press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. After it finished asking about the summary it will tell you if you want to automatically create a file to cover all that was checked so it loads every time you boot the laptop, type **Yes** and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Now reboot.

If the module does not load by any chance, simply type: `sudo modprobe i8k force=1`

If you want to monitor the Sensors, you could install the **indicator-sensor** which I found with the following PPA (I am pretty sure it was in the repositories in 11.10):

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexmurray/indicator-sensors`
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
`sudo apt-get install indicator-sensors`

Now reboot and run the indicator sensor from Dash (Should appear in the panel).

**NOTE1** - If you do the link above related to fixing the video, please download the packages from this link https://launchpad.net/~andrikos/+archive/ppa/+sourcepub/2909374/+listing-archive-extra the cover some fixes for Ati/Intel Hybrids.

Comment: Hi Luis, Thank you for the note. I am not clear what you mean to try this other URL https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/jupiter. I am only using sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webup8team/jupiter in Terminal. In terms of  editing /etc/apt/sources.list I am not sure how to do that. I also checked software sources and found nothing listed under other software services. This is new laptop (Dell Inspiron with an i7 processor) and it runs fine in Windows 7 without the fan or heating. I appreciate any other clarification. Thank you so much ! Gary

Comment: ok, here is what I type in the terminal mode

Comment: ok, here is what I type in the terminal mode    sudo add-apt-repository https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/jupiter I get an error message saying check your internet connect. Sorry to be drag this on...

Comment: After a lot of time, I still have no improvement in this problem. I have Jupiter running with Power Savings. The fan blasts loud and the system is still not useable for Ubuntu. I tried these also:                http://askubuntu.com/questions/207741/fan-speed-in-12-10-too-loud?lq=1                      http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed      http://askubuntu.com/questions/50980/linux-kernel-regression-on-power-usage

Comment: Can you add the information about the laptop to your question. That way we can check how to solve it better.

Comment: The model is:

Inspiron 15 R Special Edition,BTX,7520
Intel Core 3rd Generation Processor,I7-3612QM,  4Core
32G Solid State Drive,ISRT,A5
PWA,Daughterboard, SATA,7520
HARD DRIVE,1 Terabyte,5.4 krpm
8 GB Dual Channel DDR3 SDRAM
Intel (R) HD Graphics 4000
AMD Radeon HD 7730M
15.6 Full HD  1080 pixel LED Display

Ubuntu 12.10 is loaded as a dual boot alone on the 32 GB Solid State Drive.

Comment: Hello Luis, Thank you for the detailed information. I went thru the steps you outlined but now the system will not boot. It get stuck with a window saying you are running in low graphics mode and I hear the fan spinning at a high speed. So my Ubuntu 12.10 does not work at all. Frustrated....Gary

Comment: Try any of the answers here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error/218095#218095

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, back in January when I bought my Dell XPS.
Happily, after I installed Bumblebee and updated to the most recent Kernel version available, this problem has been fixed.
Now it works like a charm.